# Run jar file from unix command prompt (ERROR)

Tags: java, unix, command-line

I have a java project that has 10 .java files. A1.java, A2.java......A9.java and Main.java. 
The project contains a package grand.big.medium.small and all the .java files are inside this package.

I have compiled and created an executable jar file for the project using:

```
javac grand/big/medium/small/*.java
```

to run the project I used the command

```
java -cp . grand/big/medium/small/Main
```

to create the jar I used the command

```
jar -cvmf manifest.txt MyJAR.jar *.class
```

I want to run the jar file from command prompt and I am using the commad

```
java -cp . -jar grand/big/medium/small/MyJAR.jar
```

and I getting an error:
Error: Could not find or load main class Main

please can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run as:

```
java -cp . -jar grand/big/medium/small/MyJAR.jar grand.big.medium.small.Main
```

Assuming you have grand as a directory within current directory and directory hierarchy follows.

Comment: I used the command as u said and got the error
Error: Could not find or load main class Main